# Bing maps 7.0 Geocode Rest service Callback functions not called

Tags: bing

Hi I am using a bing maps 7.0 ajax api to display map. I have several addresses which i geocode to get latitude and longitude using rest services in javascript. I have setup up a GeocodeCallback method in the geocode request.

geocodeRequest = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?"+mapDataAddress[1]+"&output=json&jsonp=GeocodeCallback&jsonso="+mapDataAddress[0]+"&key="+credentials;
 CallRestService(geocodeRequest);

When the address are found i get a response in my GeocodeCallback function but for few address i dont get a response. How to figure out this status and error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out.  So basically you need to do two things.

- You need to change your URL structure.  I have found out that sometimes if I have weird address, bing will return a 400.
- use the suppressStatus parameter and set it to true.  I can't find the docs at this moment but basically I have found that if bing returns a 400,404,etc it won't actually call the callBack function.  So supressstatus says that no matter what, always return a 200.

Orignially you have:

```
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?"+mapDataAddress[1]+"&output=json&jsonp=GeocodeCallback&jsonso="+mapDataAddress[0]+"&key="+credentials;
```

So you want to do this:

```
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?addressLine="+mapDataAddress[1]+"&output=json&jsonp=GeocodeCallback&suppressStatus=true&jsonso="+mapDataAddress[0]+"&key="+credentials;
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. Although my initial enhancement for which i asked this question is on production. I created an alternate way to to resolve this by adding a timer instance and wait for some time.. if it doesnt return anything i coded accordingly.. But this one is good.. i tested this thing and it seemed to working. I will make this change in my earlier code if required.. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at the Tips and Tricks for using the Bing Maps REST services listed here: http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2013/02/14/bing-maps-rest-service-tips-amp-tricks.aspx